# http://www redirect to https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I have tried nearly all .htaccess examples on Stack overflow without success.

Ive installed a SSL cert on my website, and all pages on the site work flawlessly. my problem is my google history as well as things like adwords has the old URL http://www.example.com.

My new SSL domain is simply http://example.com

so all i want to do is make sure any incoming traffic to http://www.example.com is forwarded to the same url but https://example.com

I get errors such as domain not redirecting correctly or even worse, http://www.example.com redirecting to https://www.example.com which doesn't exist. Ive tried examples like this without success:-

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Sorry if you think this question has been asked before, but ive trying examples all around the web all without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple rule as **first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Then test this in Chrome dev tool.

Comment: Did you test in Chrome dev tool? What URL redirects does it show?

Comment: I think you may be right, I tried it just now in Google chrome and it worked!
restarted firefox and it now works, this is from the first example.

Comment: how do i see the redirect in chrome dev tools?

Comment: seams to all be ok now, the only issue is the end of the domain has two slashes ie .com//page ??

Comment: In Chrome dev tool you can click on `Net` tab, and then visit `http://www.example.com` in browser. It will then show all the redirects happening due to your rules.

Comment: yes check updated answer, `/` is not needed before `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Ive noticed that if i visit just 'example.com' this doesn't forward to the https:// is there any way to add this to the current rule, so far www.example.com works perfectly, but if the www. before the domain is not entered it does not.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` line before `RewriteCond` above.

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.yourdomain.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://yourdomain.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```